# Simple Form using Java script for show / hide entry field does not switch properly between show and hide

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to have the field "reason_for_skipping" shown when "skip_option" is "Yes" and hidden when is "No". I would like the "show / hide" action to play dynamically when "Yes" or "No" are selected. Unfortunately this is happening only after I an saving the data in database using the button "Update Option". Also under Action "Start Assessments" needs to be shown when "Skip" is "No" and "reason_for_skipping" is hidden and vice-versa. A previous version of this code using select_tag instead of f.select works as expected. I switched to the form version since I need to save the values in the database.

Here is my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@option) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <h1>Select to Start or Skip Assessments</h1>

    <br>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Skip</th>
        <th>Reason for skipping</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= link_to 'Start assessments', url_for(controller: :assessments, action: :index), id: 'start_assessment' %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.select :skip_option, options_for_select([ "Yes", "No" ], :selected => f.object.skip_option), onchange: "reason_picker()" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.text_field :reason_for_skipping, id: 'reason_for_skipping' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready (
    window.reason_picker = function () {
      var selected = document.getElementById("option_skip_option").value;
      if (selected == "Yes") {
        $("#reason_for_skipping").show();
        $("#start_assessment").hide();
      }
      else if (selected == "No"){
        $("#reason_for_skipping").hide();
        $("#start_assessment").show();
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

Not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: Have you heard about knockoutjs or angularjs? With each one of those libraries, you can do that very easy. There are a lot of examples of how to do it. You can make your life much more easier :)

Comment: I am bound to Ruby on Rails development due to the nature of my job.

Comment: angular is javascript library, you can combine it with ruby on rails or any server technology

Comment: It doesn't matter mate, you can combine it with your code. If you can use javascript in your application, then you can use any javascript library :)    Otherwise, have you tried like this? : `<td>
<% if selected == "Yes"
            <%= f.text_field :reason_for_skipping, id: 'reason_for_skipping' %>
%>
          </td>`
??

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to learn angular. That statement above seems to be syntactically incorrect. Also looks similar with that one in my java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` helper takes two options hashes, the one for html options is the **second**, so all you have to do is pass an empty hash as the first option.

```
f.select :skip_option, options_for_select([ "Yes", "No" ], :selected => f.object.skip_option), {}, onchange: "reason_picker()"
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I was dragged in other issues for a while. I will test soon the solution provide and I provide feedback.